# Intersect list of list of object and list of object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of transaction class :

```
class Transactions
{
    public Transactions()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string TransactionID { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

And a Product Class:

```
class Product
{
    public decimal ProductCode { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of Products like this:

```
List<Product> unioned = product.Union(secondProduct).ToList();
```

And I want Intersect of unioned and transaction products,
This code does not work:

```
var intersection = transactions.Where(q => q.Products.Intersect(unioned).Any());
```

I think the reason is transaction products length is variant and union length is fixed.

How can I do it?

Comment: If I get it correctly, you want to take all products from all transactions and then this list intersect with `unioned`, right?

Comment: what's the problem here?

Comment: Yes, and union list has a list of products, only two product in each list, but transaction products is variable length.

Comment: Even the first `Union` approach doesn't work correctly since you haven't overridden `Equals` + `GetHashCode` in Product. So currently only references are compared and not the `ProductCode`. Normally `Union` would remove duplicates, not yet. The second aporach doesn't work because both are different types.

Comment: As it  `transactions.SelectMany(x => x.Products).Intersect(unioned)` what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intersect is using the default equality comparer, so will do a reference check - i.e. compare that the object references are the same.

You need to [use the overload which allows you to specify an equality comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

Thus:

```
public class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
{
    public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
    {
        // TODO - Add null handling.
        return x.ProductCode == y.ProductCode;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Product obj)
    {
        return obj.ProductCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var intersection = transactions
                  .Where(q => q.Products.Intersect(unioned, new ProductComparer()).Any());
```

This test will now pass:

```
[TestMethod]
public void T()
{
    Product p = new Product { ProductCode = 10M };
    List<Product> product = new List<Product> { p };
    List<Product> secondProduct = new List<Product> { new Product { ProductCode = 20M } };
    List<Product> unioned = product.Union(secondProduct).ToList();
     var transaction = new Transactions();
     // add a different object reference
     transaction.Products.Add(new Product { ProductCode = 10M }); 

     IList<Transactions>  transactions = new List<Transactions> { transaction };

     var intersection = transactions
                  .Where(q => q.Products.Intersect(unioned, new ProductComparer()).Any());

     Assert.AreEqual(1, intersection.Count());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to solution without using `Intersect`. I use `ProductCode` to check if the `Product` is the same:

```
transactions.Where(q => q.Products.Exists(x => unioned.Exists(z => z.ProductCode == x.ProductCode))).ToList();
```

Comment: It return transactions that have one or more than on union products. I want transactions that have all of union products.

Thank you

Comment: Let me understand. What you want is transactions that have in Products all elements in unioned? So, you mean that t.Products = unioned (this is no code)?

Comment: yes I want all transactions that have all of union products.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. Thank you :-) Let me think

Comment: yeah, He answered. Thank for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
List<Product> allproductsTrans = new List<Product>();
transactions.ForEach(p => allproductsTrans.Concat(p.Products));
var result = allproductsTrans.Intersect(unioned);
```

but as **Slava Utesinov** said in the comments, the following code would do the same:

```
transactions.SelectMany(x => x.Products).Intersect(unioned)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using EqualityComparer, you can intersect ids, and then, if needed, find objects by ids.

Your example:

```
transactions.Where(q => q.Products.Select(x => x.ProductCode).Intersect(unioned.Select(x => x.ProductCode)).Any());
```

General case:

```
var ids = list1.Select(x => x.Id).Intersect(list2.Select(x => x.Id));
var result = list1.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
```